# Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax. Почему выводиться ошибка?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Здравствуйте. Учу взаимодействие php с phpmyadmin.

```
 $country = "SELECT `country`.`id` FROM `country`  
 where `country`.`country` = '".$_POST["country"]."' "; 
 $resultcountry = mysqli_query($link, $country );
 if (!$resultcountry) {
     printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
     exit();
 }
```

Выводит ошибку

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.'id' FROM 'country' where 'country'.'country' = 'Италия'' at line 1

Данные передаются методом post

Comment: phpMyAdmin тут при чем? Из вики: phpMyAdmin — веб-приложение с открытым кодом, написанное на языке PHP и представляющее собой веб-интерфейс для администрирования СУБД MySQL.

Comment: @Visman сейчас новички не понимают с чем они работают. Думают что работают с phpmyadmin, а не с СУБД.... этому можно уже не удивляться.

Comment: Разве из ошибки не ясно, что в запрос ничего не передается? Т.е. в `$_POST["country"]` ничего нет

Comment: Данный SQL  синтаксис вроде нормальный,и возле `id` нет никаких лишних символов.Чисто ради интереса уберите все обратные кавычки и попробуйте заново

Comment: Внезапно одна ошибка сменилась другой?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский удалив весь код, как посоветовал @Vanya Avchyan,  и переписав заново получаю ошибку You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `country`.`id` FROM `country` WHERE `country`.`country`=\'Англия\' ' at line 1

Comment: В ошибке говорится что перед `SELECT` есть какая то одинарная кавычка `'SELECT ...`.Откуда она берется ? Это весь ваш код возникает вопрос ? Ато по данному коду что то не должно быть `'`

Comment: `\'Англия\' ' ` Кстати почему вы экранируете,Передавайте как есть.

Comment: Ага все я понял ,это происходит из за экранирования `$_POST["country"]`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема происходила из за этого значения  `\'Англия\''` из POST.

**Решение :**

**[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)** — Экранирует специальные символы в строке для использования в SQL выражении, используя текущий набор символов соединения.

```
//...........
 $country_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['country']);
 $country = "SELECT `country`.`id` FROM `country` where `country`.`country` = '".$country_name."' "; 
 $resultcountry = mysqli_query($link, $country );
 //...........
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь. мой код почему-то заработал после нескольких перезагрузок страницы, при этом я ничего не менял))  $_POST["country"] так и остался, всё работает, странно. тем ни менее ещё раз спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @user253105  Незачто,и вам спасибо.